# Does mingw32-make be renamed to make?

Tags: mingw, mingw32

I installed the latest mingw, and found there is no mingw32-make any more. There is make.exe, so I am wondering if mingw32-make is renamed to make.exe recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know where you're getting MinGW from, but some distributions (like nuwen's) name it `make.exe`, and others name it `mingw32-make.exe` (or `mingw32-make.exe`).

I generally copy whichever one to the other, so I have identical `mingw32-make.exe` and `make.exe` in the `bin` directory. My understanding is the the name `mingw32-make.exe` is used to avoid conflicts with the `make.exe` in MSYS (see http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ).  I don't use MSYS, so having the program named `make.exe` is more convenient for me, but sometimes a build script will look specifically for `mingw32-make`.

Comment: MinGW-w64 even has a [post install script](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/MSYS/) (`/postinstall/pi.sh`) to integrate with MSYS that renames the MinGW make.exe to mingw32-make.exe. The script has a comment that describes the MinGW make.exe as "very deficient in function".  :)