# How can I use make command(MSYS) to build DCMTK?

Tags: msys, msys2, cmake-gui, dcmtk

I have used CMAKE to configure and generate DCMTK source code. Now I am trying to build libs using **make** command in **msys**. But as soon as I am passing **make** command, I am getting this:

```
212715008@G5CG7324856E /c/Ashish/dcmtkans
$ make
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.726] (c) 2017 Microsoft
> Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Why I am getting this

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.726] (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

after passing make command? I am unable to build libs. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try to write something like that `mingw32-make`

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: @Denis Sablukov thanks for the answer

Comment: After using this command I am getting some errors like this: duplicate member 'pw_passwd' OFString pw_gecos; How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need MSYS `make`, then you should install `base-devel` packages and use `make` command, otherwise, if you want to use MINGW under MSYS, then you should install `mingw` related packages (see the list there: https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Packages) and use `mingw32-make` (For some reason they named differently, there some thoughts/answers on that [Does mingw32-make be renamed to make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596137/does-mingw32-make-be-renamed-to-make))